# Office 2013 (retail) reinstall without Microsoft Account access

Tags: microsoft-office

After Windows 8.1 re-install, I need to re-install Office 2013 retail copy.
I have valid Office Product Key, but no access to my microsoft account that Office is associated with.

Any solutions to assist with re-install of Office 2013 please?